# Em jquery escrever um link diferente no a href

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho esse trecho em HTML que é chamado em algumas telas quando necessário (clicando ele abre um iframe dentro do HTML):

```
<a href="#" class="tour-360" id="tour-360-{{unit.hash}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-tour-360">
    <h3 class="title-360">
        360º Tour {{ unit.title }}
        <small>Visualize sua unidade</small>
    </h3>
</a>
```

Dependendo da {{unit.hash}}, ao invés de ser href="#" e abrir esse iframe, preciso levar o usuário para uma URL externa, abrir em uma outra aba um link. Seria algo assim(só um exemplo não funcional para explicar):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url360 = '#';
    if('{{unit.hash}}' == 's-j-dos-campos'){
        url360 = 'https://www.aurlqueeuquiser.com';
    }
</script>
<a href="<script type="text/javascript"> alert(url360); </script>" class="tour-360" id="tour-360-{{unit.hash}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-tour-360">
    <h3 class="title-360">
        360º Tour {{ unit.title }}
        <small>Visualize sua unidade</small>
    </h3>
</a>
```

Como fazer? Preciso que toda a mudança seja feita dentro desse HTML, não posso colocar arquivos externos nem nada disso.

Comment: Só será feito com esse elemento que tem a classe `tour-360` ?

Comment: Isso, só o link dele que altera

Comment: Vc pode alterar atributos com jQuery desta forma: `$(".tour-360").attr("href", url360);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que apenas o elemento com classe `tour-360` será o alvo, podes fazer algo assim:

```js
let element = $('.tour-360'), //pega o elemento pela classe
    idElement = element.attr("id"); //pega o id do elemento

if(idElement == 'tour-360-s-j-dos-campos') { //verifica se o id é = o pretendido
     element.attr('href', 'https://www.aurlqueeuquiser.com');
     console.log(element.attr("href"))
} else {
  element.attr('href', '#');
  console.log(element.attr("href"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="tour-360" id="tour-360-{{unit.hash}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-tour-360">
    <h3 class="title-360">
        360º Tour {{ unit.title }}
        <small>Visualize sua unidade</small>
    </h3>
</a>
```

Deixei o códio comentado, mas basicamente você precisará capturar o elemento, nesse caso capturei pela classe pois você informou que usará apenas esse elemento. Após capturar o elemento, basta capturar o seu atributo `id` e verificar se ele é igual ao atributo `alvo`, no caso `s-j-dos-campos`, se for, você muda a `url` do mesmo para qual você desejar, se não for, define o `href` como `#`.

Mudei o `id` do elemento para `s-j-dos-campos`, veja sendo impresso a `url` gravada no elemento:

```js
let element = $('.tour-360'), //pega o elemento pela classe
    idElement = element.attr("id"); //pega o id do elemento

if(idElement == 'tour-360-s-j-dos-campos') { //verifica se o id é = o pretendido
     element.attr('href', 'https://www.aurlqueeuquiser.com');
     console.log(element.attr("href"))
} else {
  element.attr('href', '#');
  console.log(element.attr("href"))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="tour-360" id="tour-360-s-j-dos-campos" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-tour-360">
    <h3 class="title-360">
        360º Tour {{ unit.title }}
        <small>Visualize sua unidade</small>
    </h3>
</a>
```